# Test bloc test with parameter failed

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

So, I have using this bloc_test library version `bloc_test: ^5.0.0`.
Previously I test bloc with this code and work fine

```
test(
        'should emit [RegisterLoadingState,RegisterLoadedState] when RegisterWithPassword is successful',
        () async {
      setUpSuccessfulValidateRegister();
      setUpSuccessfulRegister();

      final expected = [
        RegisterInitialState(),
        RegisterLoadingState(),
        RegisterLoadedState(account: customer),
      ];

      expectLater(bloc, emitsInOrder(expected));

      bloc.add(RegisterWithPasswordEvent(
        name: nameTest,
        email: emailTest,
        password: passwordTest,
        retypedPassword: retypedPasswordTest,
      ));
    });
```

Currently I change it with using bloc_test package and the test failed

```
blocTest(
      'should emit [RegisterLoadingState,RegisterLoadedState] when RegisterWithPassword is successful',
      build: () async {
        setUpSuccessfulValidateRegister();
        setUpSuccessfulRegister();
        return bloc;
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(RegisterWithPasswordEvent(
        name: nameTest,
        email: emailTest,
        password: passwordTest,
        retypedPassword: retypedPasswordTest,
      )),
      expect: [
        RegisterLoadingState(),
        RegisterLoadedState(account: customer),
      ],
    );
```

Here is the error in test

```
Expected: [
            RegisterLoadingState:RegisterLoadingState,
            RegisterLoadedState:RegisterLoadedState
          ]
  Actual: [
            RegisterLoadingState:RegisterLoadingState,
            RegisterLoadedState:RegisterLoadedState
          ]
   Which: was RegisterLoadedState:<RegisterLoadedState> instead of RegisterLoadedState:<RegisterLoadedState> at location [1]

package:test_api                             expect
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 124:25  blocTest.<fn>
```

the error gone if I removed the equatable in state with `account` parameter. Anyone know why this test works on the first code and failed with bloc_test packages?